# How to create folders base on external datasource in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

My goal is to **extend functionality of the current asset tracking system**.

Basically I would like to pull **list of Clients and related assets from external system into sharepoint 2010**.

Then I would like to **associate documents** with each asset. My first intention is to create a list of folders where each folder would be named respectively.
Tell me, if I am going in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open your document library in explorer view and easly copy your content from external sorce to document liabrary, as windows explorer.

You can reffer the below link for more details
http://msmvps.com/blogs/shane/archive/2006/01/12/80843.aspx

Comment: well, I would like to auto-create folder if we get a new client or asset. I am looking for an automaic(synchronised) process where it is set-up once and never touched again

Comment: ok from where the sytem copy the files? how system identify while a new client joined?

Comment: I think sharepoint can crawl external datasource. http://www.toddbaginski.com/blog/archive/2009/11/12/how-to-register-an-external-content-type-with-the-sharepoint-search-service.aspx
This way, if for example new client is created inside external datasource(database), then sharepoint will crawl it and update

Comment: if you are entering your new client in an external database, it is quest easy to create new folder in document library. You nee to create an exe for creating new folder in library. and you can call it from sql. the link helps to do it http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=54947

Comment: This just adds another level of complexity. All I want is direct connection: Sharepoint -> External DB and NOT Sharepoint -> Folders -> External DB